# Is there annotation processor factory in Intellij idea?

Tags: android, annotations, intellij-idea

Is there an annotation processor factory in Intellij idea? like eclipse
[image]

the tool gen a folder [image] in eclipse.How can we deal it with
idea IDE.or need some plug-in?

Comment: Did you try [this dialog](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/6342/20121108120612.png)?

Comment: Thank you so much .I'm careless. the default value is false.